# sqlzoo: SELECT from WORLD: Matching name and capital

Tags: sql

I'm working my way through SQLZoo, and have gotten rather stuck on the 'Matching Name and Capital' exercise. The idea is to list from the 'world' database countries that have the same first letter as their (country) name and capital, but excluding the countries where the capital is the same word as the country.
I got to:

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
WHERE LEFT(name,1)=LEFT(capital,1), name <> capital
```

That even corresponds to what's on the answers page, but leaves me with an error message on the last part of the code (name <> capital). What's the catch?

Comment: put the word `and` before name, remove the comma.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `and` in your condition instead of `,`

`WHERE LEFT(name,1)=LEFT(capital,1) and name <> capital`

Comment: Thanks - that did it.

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name , capital
FROM world
where left(name,1) = left(capital,1) and name <> capital
```

if comma does not work use and as i did

Answer (score 0):

The capital of Sweden is Stockholm. Both words start with the letter 'S'.
Show the name and the capital where the first letters of each match. Don't include countries where the name and the capital are the same word.
You can use the function LEFT to isolate the first character.
You can use != as the NOT EQUALS operator.
#sql

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
where left(name,1) = left(capital,1) and name!= capital
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct to execute that statement. However, the only replacement you have to do is remove the ","

**Your query:**
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
WHERE LEFT(name,1)=LEFT(capital,1), name <> capital

**Correction:**
select name,capital from world where name <> capital and left(name,1) = left(capital,1)

Cheers!!

Salman